# Explicitly return empty Peewee recordset

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm running a query which accepts a search parameter. If the search parameter is ever empty I'd like to explicitly return an empty record set. There are a number of other cases in which it would be useful to return an empty recordset as well. I've sifted through the docs and the only option I see is `SelectQuery`, like so:

```
users = SelectQuery(User).where(User.id==0)
```

To be clear, I want an empty queryset, but it would be nice if I didn't have to fake a where clause to get it. I'm sure something like this exists, but I'm just not seeing it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Per @coleifer, my solution is the preferred option. Import [SelectQuery](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery) and the model of your choice. Then do a simpler query which explicitly returns no results.

```
from peewee import SelectQuery
from models import User
users = SelectQuery(User).where(User.id==0)
```

Comment: Why not `User.select().where(User.id == 0)`? Seems odd to use selectquery like that.

Comment: Ideally, I'd be able to use SelectQuery without specifying a model. Then I could avoid an import of a model I don't really care about. I'm expecting the recordset to be empty which means I don't care about any of the properties of the model in question. I really just want a generic empty recordset.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.

Comment: That's okay, the SelectQuery route works just fine. It's just an extra step (and import) for the model. Thanks a lot for looking at this.

Comment: Well, what I meant is using SelectQuery(User) (which is 2 imports) when you could just do `User.select()` (1 import). No biggie.

Comment: But doesn't User.select() return all records?